# Vue JS 3 component toast auto hide

Tags: vuejs3, vue-component, hide, toast

```
<template>
    <Transition name="slide-fade">
        <div v-show="showToast" class="fixed top-4 right-4 z-50" :class="[classesPosition]">
            <div class="max-w-lg rounded-md p-4 drop-shadow-md leading-none" :class="[variantBackground]">
                <div class="flex">
                    <div class="flex-shrink-0">
                        <span class="text-2xl" :class="[variantIcon]"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ml-3">
                        <p class="text-sm font-light">{{ props.message }}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ml-auto pl-3">
                        <div class="-mx-1.5 -my-1.5">
                            <button type="button" class="inline-flex rounded-md p-1.5 focus:outline-none focus:ring-1"
                                :class="[classesCloseButton]" @click="closeToast">
                                <span class="sr-only">Dismiss</span>
                                <span class="text-xl icon-e102-x" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </Transition>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { ref, computed, watch } from "vue";

interface PropsI {
    message: string;
    variant: "info" | "success" | "warning" | "critical" | "neutral";
    position: "left" | "right" | "center";
}

const props = defineProps<PropsI>();

const showToast = ref(true);

const emit = defineEmits(["close-toast"]);
```

```
const closeToast = () => {
    emit("close-toast");
};

watch(showToast, (value) => {
    if (value) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            showToast.value = false;
        }, 3000);
    }
});
```

The above is part of my toast component

```
    <Toast v-show="info" class="mb-5" message="This toast will contain an informative message" variant="info" @close-toast="info = false"/>
    <Toast v-show="success" class="mb-5" message="This toast will contain a success message" variant="success" @close-toast="success = false"/>
```

```
    <Button
      label="Info"
      size="base"
      :isDisabled="false"
      backgroundColor="#2463eb"
      @click="info = !info"
    />

    <Button
      label="Success"
      size="base"
      :isDisabled="false"
      backgroundColor="#069668"
      @click="success = !success"
    />
```

This is where I utilize the component

I cannot get the component to auto hide after 3 seconds. The only only time it works is with unMounted and that only works once and not again. I've tried. When I only use duration=3000 it generates an error

```
<Toast v-show="info" class="mb-5" message="This toast will contain an informative message" variant="info" @close-toast="info = false" :duration=3000/>
```

watch doesn't work either
This doesn't work - I get an error

```
setTimeout(() => this.$emit('showToast'), 3000);
```